# Alignment in Minipage

Tags: minipage

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=1 in,bottom=1 in,left=0.7 in,right=0.7 in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-euclide,xcolor,graphicx}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[b]{.6\textwidth}
    \begin{flalign*}
    x^2-3x-10&=0&\\
    \therefore\;\;x^2-5x+2x-10&=0&\\
    \therefore\;\;x\left(x-5\right)+2\left(x-5\right)&=0&\\
    \therefore\;\;\left(x-5\right)\left(x+2\right)&=0&\\
    \therefore\;\;\left(x-5\right)&=0\quad \text{OR}\quad \left(x+2\right)=0&\\
    \therefore\;\;x&=5\quad \text{OR}\quad x=-2&
    \end{flalign*}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=1.2cm,
    level 1/.style={sibling distance=1.5cm},
    level 2/.style={sibling distance=1cm}]
    \tikzstyle{every node}=[circle,draw]

    \node (Root) [black] {-10}
    child {node {-5}}
    child {node {2}};

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}


\end{document}
```

Question: How can i vertically align my tikz picture in the same line of the first equation?

Comment: Just remove the first **`minipage`** aligment specifier `[b]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the picture a part of the alignment. In the code below I left only the strictly necessary packages.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\thf}{\therefore\quad}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
     & x^2-3x-10=0
&\qquad&
  \begin{adjustbox}{valign=t,set depth=0pt}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=1.2cm,
    level 1/.style={sibling distance=1.5cm},
    level 2/.style={sibling distance=1cm}]
    \tikzstyle{every node}=[circle,draw]
    \node (Root) [black] {$-10$}
    child {node {$-5$}}
    child {node {$2$}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{adjustbox}
\\
\thf & x^2-5x+2x-10=0\\
\thf & x(x-5)+2(x-5)=0\\
\thf & (x-5)(x+2)=0\\
\thf & (x-5)=0\quad \text{or}\quad (x+2)=0\\
\thf & x=5 \quad \text{or}\quad x=-2
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

Some points to note.

1. I removed `\allowdisplaybreaks` that in general is to be avoided unless we are in the writing phase (a break in this display would have disastrous consequences)
2. I removed all `\left` and `\right` that do nothing good here and something bad
3. I chose alignment with respect to the “therefore” symbol rather than alignment at `=` that seems artificial particularly for the last two lines
4. I hid the `\therefore` command in a macro so you are free to change the rendering of `\thf` to, say, `\Leftrightarrow` in case you want to underline that each line is completely equivalent to the preceding one

The trick is making the picture as high as a line of text with `valign=t` and have no depth, so TeX won't leave space for it.

You may want to increase the minimum radius of the circles.

[image]

Comment: THanks a lot for such a nice information and correction. it improve my latex knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to removing the `[b]` placement specifier from the first `minipage` environment, you should also

- use an `aligned` environment instead of an `flalign*` environment to avoid inserting vertical whitespace before the group of equations,
- insert `\noindent` immediately before the first `minipage`,
- remove the `\hfill` instruction after the first minipage and, instead, insert `%` (comment char.) immdediately after `\end{minipage}`,
- use math mode for the circled numbers, i.e., write `$-10$`, `$-5`, and `$+2$`;
- remove all `\left` and `\right` sizing instructions: They don't change any sizes, but they do end up inserting inappropriate horizontal whitespace.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=1 in,bottom=1 in,left=0.7 in,right=0.7 in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
%%\usepackage{amsmath} % is loaded by 'mathtools' package
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-euclide,xcolor,graphicx}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}

\noindent  % <---  don't forget this instruction
\begin{minipage}{.6\textwidth}
    $\begin{aligned}  % <--- 'aligned' rather than 'flalign*'
    x^2-3x-10&=0\\    % omit the '&' chars at end of lines
    \therefore\;\; x^2-5x+2x-10 &=0\\
    \therefore\;\; x(x-5)+2(x-5)&=0\\
    \therefore\;\; (x-5)(x+2)   &=0\\
    \therefore\;\; (x-5)&=0\quad \text{or}\quad (x+2)=0\\
    \therefore\;\;     x&=5\quad \text{or}\quad x=-2
    \end{aligned}$
\end{minipage}%  % <--- no \hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=1.2cm,
    level 1/.style={sibling distance=1.5cm},
    level 2/.style={sibling distance=1cm}]
    \tikzstyle{every node}=[circle,draw]

    \node (Root) [black] {$-10$} % <--- math mode for circled numbers
    child {node {$-5$}}  
    child {node {$+2$}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ohh  thank you so much for giving some nice corrections it is very helpful